# React useEffect acting strangely with checkboxes and previous data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, use-effect, use-state

So I am trying to pass in data previously selected in a form to an update version of the form. The update version of the form needs to display all previously selected data to the user and allow them to make any necessary changes.

Here is the problem I'm having. I am using a multi-select check box component. I am passing the previously selected data in to the component. When I set the selected property for component to the previously selected data using useEffect, It will let me submit the initial data or add new selections and everything functions correctly. It will not let me uncheck/remove selections. They get submitted even though they are unchecked.

If I don't use useEffect to set selected to previousData, I can not submit with the initial data but I can add and remove selections as intended. This is not acceptable though because users will most likely not make changes every time to the check boxes.

So to clarify, I can submit without making changes and add selections the first way and I can add and remove selections the second way but not submit without making changes the second way.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function UpdateMultiCheckBox({
  title,
  hint,
  data,
  previousData,
  setSelectedData,
  dotName,
}) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { checked, value } = event.currentTarget;

    setSelected((prev) =>
      checked ? [...prev, value] : prev.filter((val) => val !== value),
    );
  };

  {/* This is what is causing all the problems but it will not work without this without making a change to the selections */}
  useEffect(() => {
    let tempData = previousData?.map((a) => a.id);
    setSelected(tempData);
  }, [previousData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedData(selected);
  }, [selected]);

  const difference = data?.filter(
    (item) =>
      !previousData?.some((itemToBeRemoved) => itemToBeRemoved.id === item.id),
  );

  return (
    <fieldset className='space-y-5'>
      <div>
        <legend className='sr-only'>{title}</legend>
        <label className='text-base font-medium text-brandText'>{title}</label>
        <p className='text-sm leading-5 text-brandText'>
          Please select all that apply.
        </p>
      </div>
      {previousData?.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id} className='relative flex items-start'>
          <div className='flex h-5 items-center'>
            <input
              id={item.id}
              value={item.id}
              defaultChecked={true}
              type='checkbox'
              onChange={handleChange}
              className='h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-brandPrimary focus:ring-brandPrimary'
            />
          </div>
          <div className='ml-3 text-sm'>
            <label htmlFor={item.id} className='font-medium text-brandText'>
              {item[dotName]}
            </label>
            <span id='comments-description' className='text-brandText'>
              {hint}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      {difference?.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id} className='relative flex items-start'>
          <div className='flex h-5 items-center'>
            <input
              id={item.id}
              value={item.id}
              type='checkbox'
              onChange={handleChange}
              className='h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-brandPrimary focus:ring-brandPrimary'
            />
          </div>
          <div className='ml-3 text-sm'>
            <label htmlFor={item.id} className='font-medium text-brandText'>
              {item[dotName]}
            </label>
            <span id='comments-description' className='text-brandText'>
              {hint}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </fieldset>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the useEffect that you say is causing the problem, is setting the state with the `previousData` and loosing the `selected` state data.

If that is the case you could try the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const tempData = previousData?.map((a) => a.id);
  setSelected([...selected, ...tempData]);
}, [previousData]);
```

So now we are adding to the selected state the previousData, another way of doing it as seen in the wild:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const tempData = previousData?.map((a) => a.id);
  setSelected(prevState => [...prevState, ...tempData]);
}, [previousData]);
```

Which is effectively the same but in certain scenarios could be be useful when you only pass the state setter as a prop.